# Is there a way to determine protocol that was attempted to connect to your "HTTP server"?

Tags: debugging, gunicorn, iot, network-protocols

I have a following scenario: my client only knows, that they have a device where you are allowed to list HTTP addresses (or at least addresses that look like HTTP addresses), which will send a request to that address when they "press a button" (basicly they have a way of triggering the process based on their physical operations).

I have built a `gunicorn` server to listen for their requests, but I only get `[WARNING] Invalid HTTP request received`. This doesn't tell much, but after doing some research, it seems that this warning comes up quite often when wrong protocol was used. Also, by using `curl` I am unable to replicate the problem, no matter how I try to make the request malformed.

I would like to add something in front of the server that would be able to detect if the request received would be HTTP 2.0, 1.1, 1.0, UDP, WebSocket... whatever; I just want to know what they are sending me. I am especially interested in HTTP versions (even though curl with 1.0 vs 1.1 doesn't fail with me) and UDP as those are the most probable candidates for the problem.

Is there a nice tool for this?

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, I think of these possible solutions in varied scenarios.

You can log your request in `gunicorn` and view them if required, [here](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#logging) is a way how.

When you have your requests logged you can view them and also the responses. This way you can find out the malformed request and correct it in your device that is sending your request.

And, if you want to monitor your requests on your LAN, you can add a TCP Sniffer, or use Wireshark for that. Note: It would only log HTTP requests since, SSL is not applicable by default and you might have to configure that.

If, nothing works you can create a sample server for testing, log the complete HTTP request and response packets you receive for the particular path, and edit them the way you want.